# Header based column selection and sorting column location

Tags: excel, vba, string, collections

I would like to copy column data based on header and paste it into another sheet on specific location. I have written a code which works perfectly when in the source sheet I have those columns header that I searched for.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim myCollection(1 To 5)    As String
Dim myIterator      As Variant
Dim myRng           As Range
Dim xlcell          As Variant
Dim otherwb         As Worksheet
Dim mywb            As Workbook
Dim colCounter, i     As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mywb = ThisWorkbook


'Create a collection of header names to search through

myCollection(1) = "Name"
myCollection(2) = "Age"
myCollection(3) = "Region"
myCollection(4) = "Uni"
myCollection(5) = "Grade"


'Where to search, this is the header
Set myRng = mywb.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("A1:E1")
mywb.Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Sorted"
Set otherwb = mywb.Sheets("Sorted")
colCounter = 0
'For Each myCollection(i) In myCollection look in each item in the collection   
For i = LBound(myCollection) To UBound(myCollection)

' look through each cell in your header
 For Each xlcell In myRng.Cells 


 ' when the header matches what you are looking for
        If myCollection(i) = xlcell.Value Then 

        ' creating a column index for the new workbook
            colCounter = colCounter + 1 
            mywb.Sheets("Sheet0").Columns(xlcell.Column).Copy
            otherwb.Columns(colCounter).Select
            otherwb.Paste
        End If      

 Next
Next

otherwb.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

The problem I am facing now is that for example if it doesn't find header "Uni" in the source sheet then it put column "Grade" on to the 4th column instead of 5th column due to the column counter that I have set. Therefore, I have wrong sequence of column.

However, I would like to create the sorted sheet with defined column header. Therefore, if "Uni" is not available in the source sheet then it should paste "Uni" as a header in the sorted sheet and keep column empty then paste column "Grade".

Regards, 
Oliver

Comment: Maybe you can try `Range.Find` instead of Looping through Cells.

Comment: @Mikku could you please explain a bit?

Comment: Explanation added in the Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this:**

So basically you will use `Rang.Find` to find the name of the Column, if it is found then you can paste it on to the other sheet if it doesn't then it just aste the column header. So your sequence is not Disturbed.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim myCollection(1 To 5)    As String
Dim myIterator      As Variant
Dim myRng           As Range
Dim xlcell          As Variant
Dim otherwb         As Worksheet
Dim mywb            As Workbook
Dim colCounter, i     As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mywb = ThisWorkbook


'Create a collection of header names to search through

myCollection(1) = "Name"
myCollection(2) = "Age"
myCollection(3) = "Region"
myCollection(4) = "Uni"
myCollection(5) = "Grade"


'Where to search, this is the header
Set myRng = mywb.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("A1:E1")
mywb.Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Sorted"
Set otherwb = mywb.Sheets("Sorted")
colCounter = 0
'For Each myCollection(i) In myCollection look in each item in the collection

Dim fnd As Range

For i = LBound(myCollection) To UBound(myCollection)

    Set fnd = myRng.Find(myCollection(i))

    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

        ' creating a column index for the new workbook
            colCounter = colCounter + 1
            mywb.Sheets("Sheet0").Columns(fnd.Column).Copy
            otherwb.Columns(colCounter).Select
            otherwb.Paste
    Else
            colCounter = colCounter + 1
            otherwb.Cells(1, colCounter) = myCollection(i)

    End If

Next

otherwb.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
For Each xlcell In myRng.Cells 

        colCounter = colCounter + 1    ' increase counter even if header not found
        otherwb.Cells(1, colCounter) = myCollection(i)  ' write hader even if not found

        If myCollection(i) = xlcell.Value Then 

    ' creating a column index for the new workbook
            mywb.Sheets("Sheet0").Columns(xlcell.Column).Copy
            otherwb.Columns(colCounter).Select
            otherwb.Paste
        End If      

    Next
Next
```

It is not the most elegant solution but it will mend your code.